# SMTShowMesh with additional graphics

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen, postprocessing

I make some simulations in AceGen and AceFEM using H1 finite elements. After computations I want to present results, in particular, deformed (or undeformed) mesh with some map (e.g. stress component) and red circle which denotes some chosen point. How can I combine SMTShowMesh with Graphics[Disc[]] located at certain point?

```
<< AceFEM`;   
SMTInputData[];
SMTAddDomain["Domain1", "OL:SED3H1DFHYH1NeoHooke", {}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{"X" == 0 &, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 0}];
SMTAddEssentialBoundary[{"X" == 1 &, 1 -> 1}];
SMTMesh["Domain1", "H1", {5, 5, 5}, {{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}}, {{{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}}];
SMTAnalysis[];
SMTNextStep[1, 1];
SMTNewtonIteration[];
```

For this example I want to obtain a figure with deformed mesh in planar view xy with small red disk situated at point x=0.5, y=0.5 (in the same coordinate system as deformed mesh)

```
SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx", ViewPoint -> {0,0,Infinity}]
Graphics[Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.1]]
```

I tried to use Show[] and Rasterize[], as below, but it does not work (there is no red disc)

```
Show[Rasterize[
  SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True,"Field"->"Sxx", ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}]],
 Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.1]}]]
```

I will be grateful for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you tried to combine expressions with different `Head` in `Show` command and that doesn't work. `SMTShowMesh` produces either `Graphics` or `Graphics3D`, depending on number of FEM model dimensions and `Rasterize` command returns `Image`.

```
(* ... evaluate this after running the original analysis in the OP's question *)    
Head[Rasterize[SMTShowMesh[]]]
(* Image *)

Head[SMTShowMesh[]]
(* Graphics3D *)
```

This is one of many possible solutions. I used `Point` object, because `Disk` doesn't exist in 3 dimensions.

```
Show[
 SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Field" -> "Sxx", ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}],
 Graphics3D[{
   {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{0.5, 0.5, 1}]}
   }]
 ]
```

[image: mesh1]

You mentioned something about plotting this point in deformed coordinate system. This is how you plot the same point in initial and deformed configuration.

```
initialPt = {0.9, 0.9, 0.5};
displacement = SMTPostData[{"u", "v", "w"}, initialPt];
deformedPt = initialPt + displacement;

Show[
 SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> False, "Mesh" -> Black, "FillElements" -> False],
 SMTShowMesh["DeformedMesh" -> True, "Mesh" -> Blue, "FillElements" -> False],
 Graphics3D[{
   {Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[initialPt]},
   {Blue, PointSize[0.02], Point[deformedPt]}
   }],
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}
 ]
```

[image: mesh2]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it works!

Comment: @Binka I'm glad to help. I suggest that you upvote the answers you like and [accept](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that you like the most or the one that works for you. Please, take the quick [tour] to see how this site works.

Comment: thanks for useful advice, now I'm much more familiar with rules working on stackexchange website.